# Spring, Hibernate C3P0 Connection Pool, physical connections not closed

Tags: spring, hibernate, connection-pooling

We have used Spring, Hibernate and C3P0 connection pooling. But connections are not getting closed even though we set **maxIdleTime=3**, **maxConnectionAge=3**, **maxIdleTimeExcessConnections=1**.

Following is **dispatcher-servlet.xml** code

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbcUrl}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${user}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10"/>
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="2"/>
        <property name="acquireIncrement"  value="1"/>          
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="1"/>
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="3"/>
        <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="3"/>
        <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="1"/>        
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean"> 
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="ConfigurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
            </props>  
        </property>         
    </bean>         

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Following is **Service** and **DAO** Implementation Code

**Service Implemention Class**

```
@Service
public class SaveFeedbackServiceImpl implements SaveFeedbackService 
{ 

    @Autowired
    private SaveFeedBackDAO saveFeedbackDAO;


    @Transactional
    public void saveStudentTestFeedback(FeedbackMaster fm,String akey,int testid)
    {
        saveFeedbackDAO.saveStudentTestFeedback(fm, akey, testid);
    }
}
```

DAO Implementation Class

```
@Repository
public class SaveFeedBackImpl implements SaveFeedBackDAO
{

        @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory; 

    @Override
    public void saveStudentTestFeedback(FeedbackMaster fm,String akey,int testid)
    {


        Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(FeedbackMaster.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("accesskey", akey)).add(Restrictions.eq("testid", testid));

        FeedbackMaster fdkm = (FeedbackMaster) criteria.uniqueResult();

        fdkm.setFbq1(fm.getFbq1());
        fdkm.setFbq2(fm.getFbq2());
        fdkm.setFbq3(fm.getFbq3());
        fdkm.setFbq4(fm.getFbq4());
        fdkm.setFbq5(fm.getFbq5());
        fdkm.setFbq6(fm.getFbq6());
        fdkm.setFbq7(fm.getFbq7());
        fdkm.setFbq8(fm.getFbq8());
        fdkm.setFbq9(fm.getFbq9());
        fdkm.setFbq10(fm.getFbq10());


        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(fdkm);


        String hql = " UPDATE StudentTestDetail set testStatus=:testStatus "+
                     " WHERE accesskey = :akey and testid=:testid ";

         Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
         query.setParameter("testStatus",4);
         query.setParameter("akey",akey);
         query.setParameter("testid",testid);        
         query.executeUpdate();


    }

}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How you come to know that connections are not closing?

Comment: You can see the open connections in **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**. To see the database connections just open **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio** then expand **Management** and double click on the **Activity Monitor**, you will see the open connections for the database.

Comment: what is your wait timeout on SQL server. and are you sure about setting `maxIdleTime` for only 3 seconds?

Comment: @Amogh 1. What is wait timeout on SQL server? I have serach for this on google but it showed lock timeout and query wait. 2. I have set `maxIdleTime` to 3 seconds just for check to connections gets closed or not. `maxIdleTime` is set in the `dataSourse` configuration in the **dispatcher-servlet.xml** file.
@Amogh generally physical database connections get closed when we close the jdbc connections. I just want physical connections should get closed, as soon as it is not required, or when connection residing in the connection pool has spent more time than idle time. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry sushil as I don't know much about Ms SQL server so I don't tell you about wait time out in MSSql, I guess there must be something similar like `wait_timeout` in MySQL its a time in second after that time a connection which is in sleep mode or in non-interactive state get closed.

Comment: about `maxIdleTime` its a time(in sec) for which a connection will be kept in pool. this must be less that timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have used the following line in the **dispatcher-servlet.xml** file and now database physical connections are now closing.
 **<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>**

Answer (score 0):

Put package `com.mchange.v2.resourcepool` on debug/trace by configuring logger in log4j and you should see something like this

```
DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:1458) 16:17:27,943 BasicResourcePool - Removing expired resource: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@45e9ddca [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@75b5b0c7]

DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:962) 16:17:27,944 BasicResourcePool - Preparing to destroy resource: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@45e9ddca

DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:967) 16:17:27,946 BasicResourcePool - Successfully destroyed resource: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@45e9ddca
```

However what I am observing is that once all the connections are destroyed, the minPoolSize (15 in this test run) number of connections are created again. In my work I do not use this pool however I am just **guessing** that the basic idea of pool is to have connections ready, so even if all are idle and all need to be closed physically the pool is expected to have minimum number of pools so it recreates them.

```
DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:404) 16:18:31,019 BasicResourcePool - incremented pending_acquires: 1
DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:404) 16:18:31,020 BasicResourcePool - incremented pending_acquires: 2
DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:404) 16:18:31,020 BasicResourcePool - incremented pending_acquires: 3
DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:404) 16:18:31,020 BasicResourcePool - incremented pending_acquires: 4
DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:404) 16:18:31,021 BasicResourcePool - incremented pending_acquires: 5
DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:404) 16:18:31,021 BasicResourcePool - incremented pending_acquires: 6
DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:404) 16:18:31,021 BasicResourcePool - incremented pending_acquires: 7
DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:404) 16:18:31,022 BasicResourcePool - incremented pending_acquires: 8
DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:404) 16:18:31,022 BasicResourcePool - incremented pending_acquires: 9
DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:404) 16:18:31,022 BasicResourcePool - incremented pending_acquires: 10
DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:404) 16:18:31,022 BasicResourcePool - incremented pending_acquires: 11
DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:404) 16:18:31,023 BasicResourcePool - incremented pending_acquires: 12
DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:404) 16:18:31,023 BasicResourcePool - incremented pending_acquires: 13
DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:404) 16:18:31,023 BasicResourcePool - incremented pending_acquires: 14
DEBUG (BasicResourcePool.java:404) 16:18:31,027 BasicResourcePool - incremented pending_acquires: 15
```